# Is it possible to run 'rhc snapshot save' without temporarily disabling your application?

Tags: openshift, snapshot, openshift-client-tools

When I run `rhc snapshot save` my application is disabled during the process, and users receive a 503 message. Is it possible to avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is currently not possible to run the `rhc snapshot save` command without temporarily disabling your application.

Comment: I was hoping this wasn't the case. Thank you anyway!